# htmlのテキストボックスでtext-align:rightにすると入力した文字が左右に動く

Tags: html, css

きわめて微妙～な現象なので、説明がわかりにくく恐縮ですが
次のような当たり前の入力ボックスで

```html
<input type="text" value="12345678" style="text-align:right;" />
```

ボックス内の文字の真ん中（たとえば4と5の間）をマウスで選択して、
その前後を交互に選択状態にするように
カーソルを大きく（テキストボックスの枠の周りを回るように）動かすと
微妙に（多分1ピクセル）文字が左右に動きます。
これを抑止するにはどうすればよろしいのでしょうか？

text-alignがright以外では起きません。
ブラウザはwindows7のIE11、chromeで確認、firefoxでは起きないようです。

情報を探すにもいったいどんなキーワードにすればよいのかも思いつかないので
申し訳ありませんが、人力検索が一縷の望みです。

正直どうでもよさそうですが、クライアントがこだわるようなので…
'△`;

Comment: わずかにスクロールが生じているような現象ですね。

Comment: ありがとうございます。なるほど”スクロール”ですか。ちょっとそういう観点で調べてみます。

Comment: 確かに `element.scrollLeft` を監視していると、なぜかスクロールしてますね。
本家の人も困っているようですが、有効な対策は見つかっていないようです。
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38126465/chrome-number-field-horizontal-scroll
ここから結局 Windows 版 Chrome のバグとしてチケットが登録されていますが、昨年の 7 月から動きが見られませんし、あきらめるしかない感じがします…。
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=625631

Answer (score 5):

Google Chrome 96.0.4664.110 において、当該現象が解消されていることを確認しました。
さらに、 [menew さんがコメントにて参照されている](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/34179/html%E3%81%AE%E3%83%86%E3%82%AD%E3%82%B9%E3%83%88%E3%83%9C%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF%E3%82%B9%E3%81%A7text-alignright%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%A8%E5%85%A5%E5%8A%9B%E3%81%97%E3%81%9F%E6%96%87%E5%AD%97%E3%81%8C%E5%B7%A6%E5%8F%B3%E3%81%AB%E5%8B%95%E3%81%8F#comment34159_34179)バグチケットも同様に fixed となり、クローズされています<sup>[[1]](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=625631#c20)</sup>。

> #### Issue 625631: Text field with text-align:right can scroll horizontally<sup>[[1]](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=625631#c20)</sup>
>
> Comment 20 by ikilpatrick@chromium.org on Thu, Aug 19, 2021, 11:45 AM
> GMT+9 Project MemberStatus: Fixed (was: Untriaged)
>
> This doesn't appear to reproduce on windows at the moment. This was
> likely as a result to transitioning form controls to LayoutNG.